# Sub reports position in master report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on reports using *iReport*. What I am doing is making a subreport and using it in my master-report's group header. But when I set the subreport position **Fix relative to top** or **Float**, it displays data, but when ever I set the subreport position to **Fix relative to bottom**, it does not show any record.

So, how can I solve this problem?

Here is xml of my master report

```
 <groupHeader>
        <band height="133">
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="c52d695f-5b19-443e-a243-861ba2406c16" x="92" y="7" width="263" height="118"/>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement uuid="5e344c57-d559-4fad-b4ac-7670bb25b240" positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="41" y="49" width="200" height="28"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="visit_id">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{visit_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "report1_subreport2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
```

Comment: You can reproduce the same behavior for a basic report contains only one ***Detail*** band. Put one **textField** to this band with *positionType* = **Fix Relative to Top** and another **textField** with *positionType* = **Fix Relative to Bottom** and *isStretchWithOverflow* = **true**. If you put long text to the second **textField** will be disappear.

Comment: May be it is a "normal" behavior in such case ...